# Is a differential equation involving a multivariate function and exactly one of its partial derivatives an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I haven't taken *any* class in differential equations, so most of what I know about them is from small lectures in other classes. Please forgive my naivete.

According to someone in this [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948327/difference-between-ordinary-and-partial-differential-equations), the answer is yes: a differential equation involving a multivariate function and exactly one of its partial derivatives is indeed an ODE. However, I can't understand why.

If we have $f(x,y) = y * \frac{df(x,y)}{dx}$, don't the various values we can plug into independent variable $y$ affect the output of both $f(x,y)$ and $\frac{df(x,y)}{dx}$? Therefore, since we have multiple independent variables to worry about, we should treat this equation more as a PDE than ODE.

Please feel free to correct my way of thinking as I am a greenhorn.

Comment: This is an ODE with a parameter, not a PDE really. The method of solution will be to just treat each fixed $y$ separately and solve the equation in each case as an ODE.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x,y)=y\frac{df}{dx}$$
If $y$ is not a function of $x$ this is an ODE in which $y$ is a parameter. The solution is :
$$f=Ce^{x/y}$$
$C$ is an arbitrary constant wrt $x$. Nothing prevents $C$ to be function of $y$ or function of any other variable insofar those variables are not function of $x$. Thus in order to obtain all solutions :
$$\boxed{f=C(y)e^{x/y}}$$
where $C(y)$ is an arbitrary function.

Now consider the original equation as a PDE :
$$f(x,y)=y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
$$y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+0\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=f$$
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{0}=\frac{df}{f}$$
This implies the first characteristic equation :
$$y=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving  $\frac{dx}{c_1}=\frac{df}{f}$
$$e^{-x/c_1}f=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$e^{-x/c_1}f=F(c_1)=e^{-x/y}f=F(y)$$
with arbitrary function $F$.
$$\boxed{f(x,y)=F(y)e^{x/y}}$$
The result is consistant with the above result since $C(y)$ and $F(y)$ are both arbitrary functions.

Answer (score 0):

That is a interesting question that may diverge according to the author. Based on [Erwin Kreyszig](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470458364) (vide Sec. 12.1), he states that a equation such as
$$
u_{xx}(x,y) - u(x,y) = 0
$$
is a PDE that can be solves as an ODE since there is no $y$-derivative involved. Therefore, we can be solve it as $u^{''} - u = 0 $. The solution is
$$
u(x,y) = A(y) e^{x} + B(y) e^{-x},
$$
which is the very same solution that we have for an ODE, except by that $A$ and $B$ may depend on $y$ (in a ODE, it would be a constant). Regardless, you can treat it as an ODE to solve it.